# How can I get Mplus's "Results in Probability Scale" output via the R MplusAutomation package?

Tags: r

I'm performing a latent class analysis using Mplus, and trying to get the output into R via the MplusAutomation package (since I'm doing this many times, I want to avoid copying by hand). I'd like to grab the "Results in Probability Scale" subsection in the "Model Results" section of the Mplus output, but I'm unable to find it in the R object MplusAutomation creates from the .out file. That object contains a "parameters" data frame which includes other information from the "Model Results" section, so is it a matter of "Results in Probability Scale" being a simple transformation of the other model results data, that I could do myself in R? If not, is there some other way of recreating the results of this section from what info I *do* have in R? Or is the information I'm looking for stored somewhere else in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Results in Probability Scale"-section does not seem to be parsed by MplusAutomation.

However, you can convert the threshold parameters yourself to probability scale using the formula `prob = 1 / (1 + exp(est))`.

For example, the code below should reproduce the results in probability scale from [this UCLA example](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/mplus/dae/latent-class-analysis/):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(MplusAutomation)

# Fetch & write output from UCLA LCA-example to temp file
lca_ex_out = tempfile(fileext = '.out')
fileConn <- file(lca_ex_out)
writeLines(readLines('https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/mplus/dae/lca1.out'), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
lca_ex_result = readModels(lca_ex_out) # extract results from temp file

# select threshold parameters, covert to probability & layout in table
lca_ex_result$parameters$unstandardized %>%
  filter(paramHeader == 'Thresholds') %>%
  mutate(est_probscale = 1 / (1 + exp(est))) %>%
  select(param, LatentClass, est_probscale) %>%
  spread(LatentClass, est_probscale)
```

Output:

```
    param     1     2     3
1 ITEM1$1 0.908 0.312 0.923
2 ITEM2$1 0.337 0.164 0.546
3 ITEM3$1 0.067 0.036 0.426
4 ITEM4$1 0.065 0.056 0.418
5 ITEM5$1 0.219 0.044 0.765
6 ITEM6$1 0.320 0.183 0.471
7 ITEM7$1 0.113 0.098 0.512
8 ITEM8$1 0.140 0.110 0.619
9 ITEM9$1 0.325 0.188 0.349
```